# Angular JS - QuizApp - How to show all questions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am developing Quiz App,where in currently ,questions are being displayed one after another,which means when first question gets displayed and user selects correct option(multiple options in the form of radio button are presented to user) and click next,user can see only next question and previous question is not displayed,but what I want is,as user move through questions,all previous questions with their responses are also displayed.

Below is code :

1)index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="quizApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>QuizApp</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="title">QuizApp</h1>
    <quiz/>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

2)template.html

```
<div class="quiz-area" ng-show="inProgress">
    <div ng-show="!quizOver">



        <h2 id="question">{{question}}</h2>
        <ul id="options">
            <li ng-repeat="option in options">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="{{option}}">
                    {{option}}
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>


        <div>
            <button ng-click="checkAnswer()" class="next-question">Next</button>


        </div>
    </div>

    <div ng-show="quizOver">
        <h2>Quiz is over</h2>
        <button ng-click="reset()">Play again</button>
    </div>

    <div id="score">
        Score: {{score}}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="intro" ng-show="!inProgress">
    <p>Welcome to the QuizApp</p>
    <button id="startQuiz" ng-click="start()">Start the Quiz</button>
</div>
```

3)app.js

```
var app = angular.module('quizApp', []);

app.directive('quiz', function(quizFactory) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.start = function() {
                scope.id = 0;
                scope.quizOver = false;
                scope.inProgress = true;
                scope.getQuestion();
            };

            scope.reset = function() {
                scope.inProgress = false;
                scope.score = 0;
            }

            scope.getQuestion = function() {
                var q = quizFactory.getQuestion(scope.id);
                if(q) {
                    scope.question = q.question;
                    scope.options = q.options;
                    scope.answer = q.answer;
                    scope.trueQId = q.trueQId;
                    scope.falseQid = q.falseQid;
                    scope.answerMode = true;
                } else {
                    scope.quizOver = true;
                }
            };

            scope.checkAnswer = function() {

                if(!$('input[name=answer]:checked').length) return;

                var ans = $('input[name=answer]:checked').val();
                if(ans == scope.options[scope.answer]) {
                    scope.id = scope.trueQId;

                } else {
                    scope.id = scope.falseQid;
                }

                scope.getQuestion();
                scope.answerMode = false;
            };
            scope.reset();
        }
    }
});

app.factory('quizFactory', function() {
    var questions = [
        {
            question: "Which is the largest country in the world by population?",
            options: ["India", "USA", "China", "Russia"],
            answer: 2,
            trueQId:1,
            falseQid:3
        },
        {
            question: "When did the second world war end?",
            options: ["1945", "1939", "1944", "1942"],
            answer: 0,
            trueQId:2,
            falseQid:3
        },
        {
            question: "Which was the first country to issue paper currency?",
            options: ["USA", "France", "Italy", "China"],
            answer: 3,
            trueQId:3,
            falseQid:4
        },
        {
            question: "Which city hosted the 1996 Summer Olympics?",
            options: ["Atlanta", "Sydney", "Athens", "Beijing"],
            answer: 0,
            trueQId:4,
            falseQid:4
        },
        {   
            question: "Who invented telephone?",
            options: ["Albert Einstein", "Alexander Graham Bell", "Isaac Newton", "Marie Curie"],
            answer: 1
        }
    ];

    return {
        getQuestion: function(id) {
            if(id < questions.length) {
                return questions[id];
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
});
```

4)style.css

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial';
}

h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

button {
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.container {
    width: 480px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}

#options {
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.next-question {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#score {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: @NexusDuck...can u pls give some pointer..Thanks

Comment: Take a look here https://plnkr.co/edit/Zsmm28bhBDvh6oBlgs75?p=preview

Comment: What does "falseQid" mean?

Comment: On the basis of what option user selects,I want to decide which question should be displayed next.I am going to make available only two radio buttons actually later.

Comment: What is your exact requirement here?

Comment: On the first page,I need to show a question with two options(yes/No).On the  basis of Yes or No ,I need to chose and show next question and so on.As we pass through these questions,previous questions with their chosen answer should also be there on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

made some changes , Your template.html

```
 <div class="quiz-area" ng-show="inProgress">
 <div ng-show="!quizOver" ng-repeat="option1 in question" ng-init="parentIndex = $index">
  <h2 id="question">{{option1.question}}</h2>
  <div id="options">
     <div ng-model="selected" ng-repeat="option in option1.options">
        <label>
        <input type="radio" ng-value="option.name" ng-model="option.selectedRadio" name="myName{{$parent.$index}}">
        {{option.name}}
        </label>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div>
     <button ng-click="checkAnswer(option1)" class="next-question">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
 <div ng-show="quizOver">
  <h2>Quiz is over</h2>
    <button ng-click="reset()">Play again</button>
 </div>
    <div id="score">
     Score: {{score}}
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="intro" ng-show="!inProgress">
  <p>Welcome to the QuizApp</p>
   <button id="startQuiz" ng-click="start()">Start the Quiz</button>
  </div>
```

your app.js

```
  var app = angular.module('quizApp', []);

  app.directive('quiz', function(quizFactory) {
    return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.start = function() {
            scope.id = 0;
            scope.score = 0;
            scope.question = [];
            scope.quizOver = false;
            scope.inProgress = true;
            scope.getQuestion();
        };
        scope.reset = function() {
            scope.inProgress = false;
            scope.score = 0;
        }
        scope.getQuestion = function() {
            var q = quizFactory.getQuestion(scope.id);
            console.log(q);
            if (q) {
                scope.object = {
                    'question': q.question,
                    'options': q.options,
                    'answer': q.answer,
                    'trueQId': q.trueQId,
                    'falseQid': q.falseQid,
                    'answerMode': true,
                    'answers': q.answers
                }

                scope.question.push(scope.object);
                console.log(scope.question);
            } else {
                scope.quizOver = true;
            }
        };

        scope.checkAnswer = function(question) {
            var options = question.options;
            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                if (options[i].selectedRadio) {
                    var ans = options[i].selectedRadio;
                }
            }
            console.log(question.options[question.answer]);
            if (question.options[question.answer].name == ans) {
                console.log(ans);
                scope.score++;
                scope.question[scope.id].answerMode = false;
                scope.answerMode = false;
                scope.id++;
                scope.getQuestion();
            }
          };
        }
       }
      });

  app.factory('quizFactory', function() {
  var questions = [{
    question: "Which is the largest country in the world by population?",
    options: [{
        name: "India",
        selected: false
    }, {
        name: "USA",
        selected: false
    }, {
        name: "China",
        selected: false
    }, {
        name: "Russia",
        selected: false
    }],
    answer: 2,
    trueQId: 1,
    falseQid: 3,
    answers: ""
}, {
    question: "When did the second world war end?",
    options: [{
        name: "1945",
        selected: false
    }, {
        name: "1934",
        selected: false
    }, {
        name: "1993",
        selected: false
    }, {
        name: "2002",
        selected: false
    }],
    answer: 0,
    trueQId: 2,
    falseQid: 3
}, {
    question: "Which was the first country to issue paper currency?",
    options: [{
        name: "USA",
        selected: false
    }, {
        name: "France",
        selected: false
    }, {
        name: "Italy",
        selected: false
    }, {
        name: "China",
        selected: false
    }],
    answer: 3,
    trueQId: 3,
    falseQid: 4
}];

return {
    getQuestion: function(id) {
        console.log(questions);
        if (id < questions.length) {
            return questions[id];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
       },
      updateQuestion: function(id, ans) {
        questions[id].answers = ans;
     }
     };
   });
```

Hope it helps you(y)

Comment: Many thanks Ujjwal...This is working.Can you please tell how I can keep the state of previously selected answers as well.

Comment: I have made it work requires few hack ,Sorry for late didn't see your message . Hope It Helps.and If it does please upvote :)

Comment: @Ujjwal......Could you please help in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39861418/angularjs-decision-tree-implementation?noredirect=1#comment67011695_39861418