# AngularJS : Decision tree implementation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to write a quiz app.Below is the source code.Currently it is working like as below :

1. On Click start Quiz,first questions shows up.
2. User selects correct option and it moves to say question number 3.
3. if User selects wrong option,it moves to another question say question number 4.

and so on...

Please check link http://plnkr.co/edit/sYG9jjX0JATbQhJ1hNf6

What I want to achieve is as below :

1. On Click start Quiz,first questions shows up.
2. User selects correct option and it moves to say question number 3.
   Now at this time,there are two questions on the screen(1st and 3rd).
3. Now say user changed the option in 1st question and selected any other answer,3rd question should go off and another question(say question number 4) should be displayed.
4. If user has already browsed through 3-4 questions and then changes option of say first question then only next possible question should be displayed and not all 3-4 questions.

Please find below code :

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="quizApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>QuizApp</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="title">QuizApp</h1>
    <quiz/>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

template.html

```
<div class="quiz-area" ng-show="inProgress">
 <div ng-show="!quizOver" ng-repeat="option1 in question" ng-init="parentIndex = $index">
  <h2 id="question">{{option1.question}}</h2>
  <div id="options">
     <div ng-model="selected" ng-repeat="option in option1.options">
        <label>
        <input type="radio" ng-value="option.name" ng-model="option.selectedRadio" name="myName{{$parent.$index}}">
        {{option.name}}
        </label>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div>
     <button ng-click="checkAnswer(option1)" class="next-question">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
 <div ng-show="quizOver">
  <h2>Quiz is over</h2>
    <button ng-click="reset()">Play again</button>
 </div>
    <div id="score">
     Score: {{score}}
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="intro" ng-show="!inProgress">
  <p>Welcome to the QuizApp</p>
   <button id="startQuiz" ng-click="start()">Start the Quiz</button>
  </div>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('quizApp', []);

  app.directive('quiz', function(quizFactory) {
    return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.start = function() {
            scope.id = 0;
            scope.score = 0;
            scope.question = [];
            scope.quizOver = false;
            scope.inProgress = true;
            scope.getQuestion();
        };
        scope.reset = function() {
            scope.inProgress = false;
            scope.score = 0;
        }
        scope.getQuestion = function() {
            var q = quizFactory.getQuestion(scope.id);
            console.log(q);
            if (q) {
                scope.object = {
                    'question': q.question,
                    'options': q.options,
                    'answer': q.answer,
                    'trueQId': q.trueQId,
                    'falseQid': q.falseQid,
                    'answerMode': true,
                    'answers': q.answers
                }

                scope.question.push(scope.object);
                console.log(scope.question);
            } else {
                scope.quizOver = true;
            }
        };

        scope.checkAnswer = function(question) {
            var options = question.options;
            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                if (options[i].selectedRadio) {
                    var ans = options[i].selectedRadio;
                }
            }
            console.log(question.options[question.answer]);
            if (question.options[question.answer].name == ans) {
                console.log(ans);
                scope.score++;
                scope.question[scope.id].answerMode = false;
                scope.answerMode = false;
                scope.id++;
                scope.getQuestion();
            }
          };
        }
       }
      });

  app.factory('quizFactory', function() {
  var questions = [{
    question: "Which is the largest country in the world by population?",
    options: [{
        name: "India",
        selected: false
    }, {
        name: "USA",
        selected: false
    }, {
        name: "China",
        selected: false
    }, {
        name: "Russia",
        selected: false
    }],
    answer: 2,
    trueQId: 1,
    falseQid: 3,
    answers: ""
}, {
    question: "When did the second world war end?",
    options: [{
        name: "1945",
        selected: false
    }, {
        name: "1934",
        selected: false
    }, {
        name: "1993",
        selected: false
    }, {
        name: "2002",
        selected: false
    }],
    answer: 0,
    trueQId: 2,
    falseQid: 3
}, {
    question: "Which was the first country to issue paper currency?",
    options: [{
        name: "USA",
        selected: false
    }, {
        name: "France",
        selected: false
    }, {
        name: "Italy",
        selected: false
    }, {
        name: "China",
        selected: false
    }],
    answer: 3,
    trueQId: 3,
    falseQid: 4
}];

return {
    getQuestion: function(id) {
        console.log(questions);
        if (id < questions.length) {
            return questions[id];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
       },
      updateQuestion: function(id, ans) {
        questions[id].answers = ans;
     }
     };
   });
```

Comment: What's the question? What is the code doing that you don't want it to? What is the code not doing that you do want it to? See [ask] for more information on how to ask a good question, and you might look into how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Added code in plunker and updated link in above question to reproduce the scenario.Question is -> Currently on the basis of trueQId and
    falseQid,it choses which next question should be displayed,which is working fine,but what I want is -> if user changes his/her option ,then accordingly suitable question(as configured using trueQId and
    falseQid) should be displayed and next question which came on selection of previous option should go off.

Comment: For Example: On Selecting China(true answer),question 1(trueQId),i.e.  "When did the second world war end?" is coming,but now if user changes option to USA(false ans),then question 3 (falseQId)i.e. "Which city hosted the 1996 Summer Olympics?" should come and question 1 should go off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Your checkAnswer function like this

```
        scope.checkAnswer = function(question) {
            console.log(question);
            var options = question.options;
            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                if (options[i].selectedRadio) {
                    var ans = options[i].selectedRadio;
                }
            }
            console.log(question.options[question.answer]);
            if (question.options[question.answer].name == ans) {
                console.log(scope.id);
                scope.score++;
                scope.question[scope.id].answerMode = false;
                scope.answerMode = false;
                scope.id++;
                scope.getQuestion();
            }else{
                scope.question=scope.question.slice(0,question.trueQId);
                console.log(scope.question);
                scope.id=question.falseQid-1;
                scope.getQuestion();
            }
          };
```

It will give you understanding ,How to do it .. Thanks